# Cassandra nodetool status output is inconsistent across nodes

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

I have a cassandra cluster with only two nodes (EC2 instances) on the same region. And I  inserted 70GB of data into a table of a keyspace with replication factor of 1.

The data is distributed fine between my nodes. The first one has around 30GB of data and the second one has around 40GB.

```
ubuntu@cassandra1:~/storage/cassandra_data/data$ du -sh .
30G .
```

```
ubuntu@cassandra2:~/storage/cassandra_data/data$ du -sh .
40G .
```

However, when I use `nodetool status` command, each node claims that it owns around 99% of my data, even though my replication factor is 1.

Here is the output of the command on my first node:

```
ubuntu@cassandra1:~/apache-cassandra-4.0.5/bin$ nodetool status
Datacenter: eu-central-1
========================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.31.8.94   39.85 GiB  16      1.1%              63a6fc88-41c5-42f3-8782-c67be4df70e5  eu-central-1c
UN  172.31.8.187  29.97 GiB  16      98.9%             e1de2f4c-1a7e-4329-80f1-91b47cde9d43  eu-central-1c
```

And this is its output on my second node:

```
ubuntu@cassandra2:~/apache-cassandra-4.0.5/bin$ nodetool status
Datacenter: eu-central-1
========================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.31.8.94   39.85 GiB  16      99.1%             63a6fc88-41c5-42f3-8782-c67be4df70e5  eu-central-1c
UN  172.31.8.187  29.97 GiB  16      0.9%              e1de2f4c-1a7e-4329-80f1-91b47cde9d43  eu-central-1c
```

**More information about my cluster:**

- cassandra_version: 4.0.5
- endpoint_snitch: Ec2Snitch
- partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.ByteOrderedPartitioner

Comment: A friendly reminder that Stack Overflow is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. If you post it there, I'd be happy to help. Cheers! 

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I posted my question there. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/315194/nodetool-status-is-inconsistent-in-different-nodes @ErickRamirez

Comment: Thanks for doing that. I'm looking at it now and will respond on DBA Stack Exchange. Cheers!